# Adding location points to a graph of roads using osmium and finding the closest roads

Tags: graph, osmium

I am using c++ 11 and [libosmium 2.13.1](https://docs.osmcode.org/libosmium/v2.13.1/). In my project I need a graph of roads of an area and I I have figured that part out. My problem is with adding locations to that graph that are not located on the intersections of these roads. **How could I find the closest road to given coordinates so that I may connect that location to the road's nodes in graph?**
If searching for the closest road from the entire map would be too hard, then maybe it would be possible to search if there are any roads in a 50m radius of the location for any roads that go through that circle?